# The necessary analyses to perform on a dataset before running a GEE

Tags: regression, time-series, panel-data, stata

I'm working with a data set in Stata that spans over 3 years. I paneled the data using `xtset` and I was wondering if I needed to do anything else before running a `xtgee`?

I just want to make sure that the results I got for the `xtgee` I ran are valid in order to compare the results of my robust random and fixed effects regressions controlling for each year using `i.year`.

Comment: Essentially a repeat of http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/259289/what-are-the-steps-needed-to-do-before-a-gee-analysis-in-stata

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the examples in the Stata xtgee help you should have good guidance on what to do.

Imagine you have the following dataset:

[image]

In case you want to check the association between gender and changes in C-reactive protein over time (e.g. after statin therapy has been initiated), you just need to enter the following code:

```
xtset id phase
xtgee crp female, family(gaussian) link(identity)
```

With the following results:

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for clarifying. This is exactly what I did, and I just wasn't sure if this was the correct way to run this.